# help text for contents of a calendar link

Tags: google-calendar

We have links on our front page that go to our embedded Google calendar.
I'd like to make it so when someone hovers their mouse over one of these links a "help text" appears with the contents of the event. Is this even possible?

Currently we just have it so the links go to the specific event instead of our embedded calendar page, which works great if the user is logged in to a Google account, but not so hot if they're not.